# Reorder table rows based on column value not ascending or descending

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter, html-table

So, I have a table that on the front end looks like this
[image]

The buttons at the top are what I'm trying to make work. Basicaly they are like price segments, where by pressing on the table should rearrange it's row based on the selected value. So, if 1500 - 2000 is selected then every user in that segment should be first in the table.

Below is my `html` markup.

```
<form action="" id="segments">
    <input type="radio" id="0-level" name="level" value="менее €500">
    <label for="0-level">less than €500</label>

    <input type="radio" id="1-level" name="level" value="€500 - €1000">
    <label for="1-level">€500 - €1000</label>

    <input type="radio" id="2-level" name="level" value="€1000 - €1500">
    <label for="2-level">€1000 - €1500</label>

    <input type="radio" id="3-level" name="level" value="€1500 - €2000">
    <label for="3-level">€1500 - €2000</label>

    <input type="radio" id="4-level" name="level" value="€2000 - €2500">
    <label for="4-level">€2000 - €2500</label>

    <input type="radio" id="5-level" name="level" value="более €2500">
    <label for="5-level">more than €2500</label>

  </form>
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Money spend</th>
        <th>Last login</th>
        <th>Send Newsletter</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-segment-level="2" class="subscribed">
        <td>jack bishop</td><td>abc@site.com</td>
        <td>€1,189.38</td><td>08/06/2020   </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="emailstosend" name="emailstosend" value="abc@site.com">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr data-segment-level="5" class="subscribed">
         <td>Jack Mimo</td>
         <td>email@site.com</td>
         <td>€15,345.78</td>
         <td>05/06/2020   </td>
         <td>
           <input type="checkbox" class="emailstosend" name="emailstosend" value="email@site.com">
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have added `data-segmnent-level` attribute to each row with the value depending on the money spend by that row/user. They correspond with the radio buttons at the top starting with 0 and ending with 5.

Any help is much appreciated, since I'm completely stuck!

Answer (score 2):

ok you have to use javascript or jquery ,I will show you a general solution

link app.js file to your HTML file, instead of putting your data statically in HTML put it in a js object like this:

```
users = [
    {name:'Jack Bishop', email:'ex@ex.com', MonySpent:'1300'}
    ...
]
```

for the initial opening of the page, you can just inject HTML without any sorting to your table, and when the user clicks on any of the buttons you have to call a function that will 
1- empty the table
2- sort users Array with requested arrange
3- inject sorted users Array to table

you can inject HTML to table like this:

```
('.sortable tbody').append(
     '<tr data-segment-level="5" class="subscribed">' +
     '<td>' + users[counter].name + '</td>' +
     '<td>' + users[counter].email + '</td>' +
     ...
     '</tr>'  
)
```

Comment: The table is populated with PHP code, it's a WordPress site. I can use both, jQuery or Vanilla, but since jQuery is already loaded might as well use that.

Comment: I don't know how WordPress works but if you can change the code that loads table in the first place and add event listeners to it you should try my approach in the same script because the user's Array must  be defined or fetched there